# why return array doesn't work in function in c#

Tags: c#, function, return

I'm writing a project for school and I had a problem while writing the code.
I'm trying to return 2 integers in an array but it doesn't work for me...
can somebody help me?

```
public static int[] generation(char[,] people)
    {

        int neighbors = 0;
        int[] changes = new int[2];
        changes[0] = 0; //alive
        changes[1] = 0; // dead
        for (int i = 0; i < people.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < people.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                neighbors = cell_state(i, j - 1, people) + cell_state(i, j + 1, people) + cell_state(i + 1, j, people) + cell_state(i - 1, j, people) + cell_state(i - 1, j - 1, people) + cell_state(i + 1, j + 1, people) + cell_state(i - 1, j + 1, people) + cell_state(i + 1, j - 1, people);
                if (neighbors <= 1)
                {
                    people[i, j] = '+';
                    changes[1] =+ 1;
                }
                if (neighbors > 3)
                {
                    people[i, j] = '+';
                    changes[1] =+ 1;

                }
                if (neighbors == 3)
                {
                    people[i, j] = '0';
                    changes[0] =+ 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return changes;

    }
```

then In the main I wrote this:

```
    int[] changes = new int[2];
    changes = generation(people);
                born_counter = changes[0];
                died_counter = changes[1];
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What error do you get and which line is it on?

Comment: `changes[1] =+ 1;` seems strange to me, you probably want `changes[1] += 1;`., don´t you?

Comment: To better understand your question, we need more information. 

I want to help, but unsure of the goal of your algorithm. 

Can you add some comments to code, answering these questions? 
What is the goal of the code? 
Why is this being done? 
Comment individual variables / functions to explain their meaning / purpose / what they represent? 

Can you describe "does not work" better? What is the expected result, current result, and why does this not work?

Comment: What is valid input into the function? What is invalid input? 

What is the overall algorithm (if publicly available), and goal of this code / exercise? 

I could make 50 different guesses on what "generation", "people", "neighbors", "changes", "alive", or "dead" mean. It would help to comment these variables.

Thanks for submitting your question, and hope you can provide this change, so that we all can help you with this code. It seems interesting to me, but I'm unsure of the finer details.